# Migrating development Google Maps Geocoding API key to production

Tags: google-geocoding-api

I am developing a small application for a small non-profit organization.  The app uses Google Maps Geocoding API. For development, I used my google account to obtain the API key.   Now that development is wrapping up it is time to get a key for production.  This obviously should not be a key from my account but an account that represents the organization.

I am chagrined to realize that I don't know how to set up a business account. It should be obvious, but the only Google account setups I can find are for individuals.  Can someone explain the appropriate account to use and point to where it can be set up?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The only way your customer organization will have sole ownership of the developer project (including its credentials) is for someone in their org to create it.

They need a Google account to be able to do so, so they need to [sign up](https://accounts.google.com/SignUpWithoutGmail?dsh=-7646927050426900608&continue=https%3A%2F%2Faccounts.google.com%2FManageAccount#FirstName=&LastName=) for one if they don't already have one. They can even use their existing email address with the account, if they don't want a gmail.com one.

Once they have an account, they just have to [create a project and get a key](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/get-api-key), as explained in the Google Maps Geocoding API developer docs.

They should also make sure to [add more owners](https://support.google.com/googleapi/answer/6158846?hl=en&ref_topic=7014522), as explained in Google API Console Help Center.
This will make sure they won't lose access to the project if the original owner decides to leave. As also described in the article, they can either add individual Google accounts or a private Google Group as owners, whichever works best for them.

If you still need to have access to their project, you have to ask them to also add you to it. If they need you to maintain their API keys, a project editor role should be sufficient for you as a developer. If you only need access to their usage reports to verify things are working, a project viewer role should be enough.

Answer (score 0):

You can also request an uplift through the [Google Maps APIs Grants Application](https://services.google.com/fb/forms/mapsapiuplift/) form. Bear in mind this needs to be reviewed, takes some time, and may not be granted. Failing this, the options in the other answer are always available.